# Creating XPATH from parent class with Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-ide

If anybody knows how to finish writing XPATH to pin point high lited option from the drop-down menu. I am trying to print selected option. So far, I got to :

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//[@id='productGrid']/div[1]/div[1]/div/select").text)
```

This prints all avaialable options like so:

Featured

```
                        Name (A-Z)                        

                        Name (Z-A)                        

                        Price (Low-High)                        

                        Price (High-Low)
```

I just need option 'Name A-Z' to be printed but do not know how to locate this particular option of an element with XPATH. Looks like I need to write something in XPATH to get to the child subclass. The parent class is: id='productGrid'.
'select' is a subclass. 'option value' = Name (A-Z) is the next step I can not get to.

Fire Path script looks like this:

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">  **(I am here** )

<option value="http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-     gloves?dir=desc&order=position">   Featured </option>

<option value="http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-gloves?dir=asc&order=name" selected="selected">   Name (A-Z) </option> (*I need to get here*)

<option value="http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-gloves?dir=desc&order=name">   Name (Z-A) </option>

<option value="http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-gloves?dir=asc&order=price">   Price (Low-High) </option>

<option value="http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-gloves?dir=desc&order=price">   Price (High-Low) </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *If anybody knows how to finish writing XPATH to pin point high lited option from the drop-down menu. I am trying to print selected option*

You can just add `selected` attribute check to your XPath :

```
.//*[@id='productGrid']/div[1]/div[1]/div/select[@selected='selected']
```